# Sync between Azure AD and on-premise AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When we remove the synchronization of Azure AD with on-premises AD, will we be able to update the on-premises objects/users which are in Azure AD (since most of the properties are read-only [when synchronized with on-premises])?
If not?
Does creating a second tenant and synchronizing with first tenant a good idea? and if I will be able to update the objects of on-premises users (but then it will be objects of first tenant)?

I tried getting the data from Graph API and then updating the on-premises AD, but I am thinking, eventually I will get rid of on-premises AD, so how to manage on-premises object in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

> Sync between Azure AD and on-premise AD

When you remove the synchronization of `Azure AD` with the on-premises `Active Directory` the on-premises objects/users that were synchronized to `Azure AD` will act as cloud-only objects. These objects will be managed solely within `Azure AD`, and any changes made to them will need to be done directly in [Azure AD](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory-domain-services/synchronization.md)

The properties of cloud-only objects in `Azure AD` are not read-only like their synchronized counterparts.

You cannot reset the password of an `on-premises AD` user from the portal.

[image]

To update the password of an on-premises user object, you can use below script.

```
    Import-Module AzureAD
    Connect-AzureAD
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@ssW0rD!fff" -Force –AsPlainText
    $user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID "UserobjID"
    Set-AzureADUserPassword -ObjectId  "UserobjID"  -Password $Password
```

**Output:**

[image]

Creating a second tenant and synchronizing it with the first tenant is not a recommended approach for managing      on-premises objects in Azure AD. It would lead to unnecessary complexity and potential data inconsistency between the two [tenants](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/hybrid/connect/how-to-connect-install-existing-tenant.md) in your domain.

If you plan to eventually get rid of the `on-premises AD` and solely rely on Azure AD, it is recommended to manage the on-premises objects as cloud-only objects within Azure AD. You can use Azure AD PowerShell or [Microsoft Graph API](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/hybrid/configure.md) to manage and update these objects directly in Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, however I want to further explain my problem. 
I want to synchronize the Azure AD data with 3rd party vendor (who have API's to sync data with Azure), but the problem is with those API's I am not able to update cloud-only objects. 
That's the reason of thinking about the solution with 2 tenants, Where from one tenant I can sync data from vendor API and with one tenant from on-premises AD, and then doing cross tenant synchronization periodically. 
So, at later stages, if I want to remove the on-premises AD, my new tenant will be in sync and can be primary

Comment: If you have one tenant synchronized with your on-premises AD, and another tenant synchronized with the 3rd party vendor's API. You can periodically synchronize data between the two tenants to keep them in sync. This way, you can leverage the vendor's API to update the on-premises objects in one tenant, and then synchronize those changes to the other tenant.

Comment: That was my understanding. Thanks for the clarification and help.